# HTTP POST between Postman and EventHub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Can someone help me. I want to send data from Postman (Chrome APP) to my EventHub via HTTP POST. I was successful a while ago but have lost the documentation.

I have the following credentials:
EventHub URL in the form https://NAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/EVENTHUBNAME/messages

DataSend name

DataSend key

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We recently updated our REST documentation - guess SEO is taking its sweet time.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790664.aspx) the documentataion.

Most crucial among all is to generate the `SharedAccessSignature` token. Use: [`SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.GetSharedAccessSignature()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.sharedaccesssignaturetokenprovider.aspx) or [`SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.GetPublisherSharedAccessSignature()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.sharedaccesssignaturetokenprovider.getpublishersharedaccesssignature.aspx) from ServiceBus SDK to generate it, based on your scenario.
Here's the sample Rest request:

```
POST https://SBNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/EVENTHUBNAME/messages

HEADERS:
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=sb%3a%2f%2fSBNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net%2fEVENTHUBNAME%2fPublishers%PUBLISHER_NAME&sig=%2bbkNx23XC%2bWiFjD7%2bZi8qcDULdcnOEdLuef4dgEulx8%3d&se=1473789915&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
x-ms-retrypolicy: NoRetry

BODY:
{ "DeviceId":"dev-01", "Temperature":"37.0" }
```

[Here's a code Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token) to create the `SharedAccessSignature` & avoid calling SERVICEBUS SDK.

Comment: Can you create the SharedAccessSignature without the ServiceBus SDK?

Comment: @DauleDK They added [code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token) for that in the meantime.