# What are the proper arguments for the generation of a SAS token to connect to Azure eventhub?

Tags: java, azure, sas-token

While reading this [HTTP POST between Postman and EventHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451705/http-post-between-postman-and-eventhub), I was directed to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#java

I don't know what `resourceUri`, `keyName`, and key to use. Do I use the full URL for the `eventHub`?

Maybe somebody here could clarify where to get these three parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know what `resourceUri`, `keyName`, and key to use. Do I use the full url for the `eventHub`?

You can get these three parameters from the azure portal as shown in the below screenshot:

--> Goto your EventHub Namespace -->shared access policies--> Select default shared access policy(**RootManageSharedAccessKey**)-->copy `Connection string–primary key`.

[image]

These are the parameters we need to pass to that method for generating the SAS token.

```
Endpoint=sb://mmxxxxxxxdows.net/; 
SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;
SharedAccessKey=K4Qxxxxxxxxxxxx9o=
```